# How can I switch Content Views with an water-effect transition?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

In the Photos app, there is a nice water drop effect used for transition. I had seen an app a while ago that used this same water effect transition for it's content views.

Unfortunately, this transition type is not listed in the UIViewAnimationTransition documentation. But since this third party app used it (I don't remember it's name), I guess that there is a way of using it.

Does anyone know?

Comment: i am looking at the photos app - dont see a water drop transition?  What exactly are you referring to??

Comment: when you start the slideshow in the photo app, then it comes! (on my ipod touch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a hidden `CATransition` type:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = @"rippleEffect";
transition.duration = 5.0f;
transition.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[self.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```

(Note: I haven't tried this for `rippleEffect` but I have used `suckEffect` and `spewEffect` similarly)

Comment: thanks! I tried that, but seems to not work on the simulator. Is that private API stuff?

Comment: The simulator only supports most of the public animation types; the private ones such as suckEffect will show as a fade transition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the published SDK. If you want to sell your app in the app store, you need to implement this yourself.

Comment: actually i would it make for free... but i guess that makes no difference ;)